# Density of $C^\infty$ functions on $C[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm reading Peter Lax functional analysis, and the author assess that that there exits for every $f \in C[-1,1]$ so that $f(0)= 0$ a $C^\infty$ function $g$ such that the distance between $f$ and $g$ is less that $c$ for every $t \in [1,1]$ and $0$ does not belong to the support of $g$. I know that  $C^\infty$ is a dense subset with the maximum norm on $C[a,b]$ (Weierstrass theorem about polynomials), but it is not clear to me why I can chose $g$ with the support of $g$ not containing $0$.

Comment: I'm affraid you need the concept of $C^\infty$ with compact support (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function ). Take $h \in C^\infty$ approximating $f$ on $[-1,1]$, and set $g(x) = h(x) (1-u_\epsilon(x))$ where $u_\epsilon$ is a $C^\infty$ with compact support approximation of $1_{|x| < \epsilon}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c >0$. Then Weierstrass theorem implies that there is a smooth $g_1$ so that $|f(t) - g_1(t)| <c/4$ for all $t\in [-1,1]$. Since $f(0) = 0$, there is $0< \delta <1/2$ so that $|f(t)| < c/4$ for all $t\in (-\delta, \delta)$. Now let $h_2$ be a smooth function so that $0\le h_2\le 1$ and

$$h_2(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t\in [-\delta/2, \delta /2], \\ 0 & \text{if } t\notin (-\delta, \delta).\end{cases}$$

Then $g_2 := g_1 h_2$ satisfies $g_2 = g_1$ on $[-\delta/2, \delta/2]$ and $|g_2(t)|< c/4$. Thus setting $g = g_1 - g_2$ gives

$$| f(t) - g(t)| \le |f(t) - g_1(t)| + | g_2(t)| < c/2 < c$$

and $g$ has compact support away from $0$.